# Personal Information / Compliance in SaaS for US-based customers

Tags: compliance

What compliance issues should any B2B SaaS provider worry about when saving user information to its databases such as Name, DOB, Gender, Emergency Contact Information (Name, Phone, Address), etc.

Does any of this trigger HIPAA or anything like that?

Comment: Hi Chris, and welcome to Security.SE.  Your question seems to be largely legal in nature.  I'm wondering if you might have more luck at the legal.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but I can provide a general answer.

HIPAA would only be involved if you're storing data related to health care, such as appointments or communication between a patient and health care provider.

However, you'd be in scope for various privacy regulations both extant and proposed, because you're dealing with personally identifiable information (PII).

Notably, there are several states with privacy regulations that this information would be patently in scope for:  California, Nevada and Massachusetts.

The soon-to-be-effective California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA) would also introduce GDPR-like protections to this data for US-based customers.

Here's a short summary from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data#United_States):

California

- The California state constitution declares privacy an inalienable right in Article 1, Section 1.
- California Online Privacy Protection Act (OPPA) of 2003
- SB 1386 requires organizations to notify individuals when PII (in combination with one or more additional, specific data elements) is known or believed to be acquired by an unauthorized person.
- In 2011, the California State Supreme Court ruled that a person's ZIP code is PII.

Nevada

- Nevada Revised Statutes 603A-Security of Personal Information

Massachusetts

- 201 CMR 17.00: Standards for The Protection of Personal Information of Residents of the Commonwealth[34]
- In 2013, the Massachusetts Supreme Court ruled that ZIP codes are PII.[35]